# Selectable TextView doesnot work when used within a ListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, textview, xamarin.android

I created custom renderer for a Xamarin Forms Label control in order to enable text selection and AutoLink feature. It works great. But when i use the Control inside a ListView it's not triggering selection mode. When i long press on the text i see following message in my output window.

> W/TextView( 2440): TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.

Any ideas on how to make this work inside a ListView?

Below is my implementation for this control.

Control definition in PCL

```
 public class LinkLabel:Label
    {
    }
```

Custom Renderer for Android

```
class LinkLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.AutoLinkMask = Android.Text.Util.MatchOptions.All;
                Control.SetTextIsSelectable(true);
                Control.Focusable = true;
                Control.FocusableInTouchMode = true;

               //line below was required to make autodetected links clickable when used inside a ListView. Worked fine outside ListView without this line.
                Control.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is how my xaml looks for ListView, i am using LinkLabel control inside a ViewCell.

```
   <ListView x:Name="NotesListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"
              HasUnevenRows="True" >

      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>

              <StackLayout Spacing="4"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >

                <!--Notes-->

                <Controls:LinkLabel Text="{Binding Notes}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ListItemHeader}"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding FormattedDetails}"
                         Style="{StaticResource ListItemDetail}"/>
              </StackLayout>

          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I have used your code it works fine with me. Please refer to my [github](https://github.com/mikexxma/AutoLink_Xamarin_Lable)

Comment: @MikeMa Thanks, I downloaded your repo and tried it on Kitkat and Lollipop emulators. it was not working. But i saw it was working after a while. Then i realized an interesting pattern; the selection on label only works after you click on the entry control. But if you do not interact with entry control and try selecting the label it won't work. Would you mind checking if you are seeing the same behavior. You can try removing Entry control and see if that works, also what android version did you try this on?

Comment: I tried it on android 6.0 api level 23 and android 5.0 api level 21 it works fine. Just click the linklable the so website will be opened. Both emulators are google emulator not xamarin emulator. If you do not mind I can add the gif picture in the answer.

Comment: @MikeMa The problem is not with the Links, links are working fine. This issue is i am not able to select the text in textview on long press.